# Is there tractable way to use Determinantal Point Process for bulky sets?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, sampling

I want to use a method to select a diverse subset of a bulky set, to which the Determinantal Point Process is a solution. However, based on my basic knowledge of DPP, the first step is making a matrix of $N*N$ (the Gram matrix), in which $N$ is the main set size.
As $N$ for my problem is about $10^6$.

I want to know that is there any version of DPP that can tractably sample from a set with that size? Is it possible to not calculate the Gram matrix explicitly?

It would be great to introduce resources that can fit into my context.

Thanks